# What can cause ICMP Destination Unreachable (Port unreachable) over localhost

Tags: network-programming, udp, datagram

I've written a program that can connect to another instance of the same program. I run both and they work for a time, happily sending data back and forth. But randomly, things mess up. Through Wireshark, I see that I'm getting ICMP Destination Unreachable (port unreachable) messages.

After testing this over two computers on the local network; the same issue occurred.

It appears to be random. I.e., everything is working correctly up until it decides to send these messages.

Does anyone have any idea what can cause this?

Answer (score 0):

In UDP it is the equivalent of a TCP 'connection refused', i.e. nothing listening at the target port.

Comment: Can my app simply lose the binding it's made to a socket?

Comment: Your app didn't make a 'binding to a socket'. It bound a socket to a port. The only way to lose that is to close the socket.

Comment: This didn't occur. The socket was not closed.